# Python: combine two data frames with all combinations of index

Tags: python, dataframe, merge, melt

I have a data frame with x variables and an id_number 1:n (n is large). I want to create a new data frame that horizontally merges each pair based on id_number from the data frame.
Original data looks like this:

```
id_number   var_x1   var_x2   
1           sth      stuff   
2           other    things  
3           more     info
```

I want to get this for every possible pair:

```
id_numberA  var_x1A var_x2A id_numberB var_x1B var_x2B
1           sth     stuff   1          sth     stuff
1           sth     stuff   2          other   things
1           sth     stuff   3          more    info
2           other   things  3          more    info
```

What is the most efficient way to do this for a large dataset?

Comment: Why in the requested output is there a combination of `id = 1` with itself, but there isn't a combination of `id = 2 (or 3)` with itself?

Comment: Because combination of id=1 and id=2 is already done in the second row, so it's not necessary to combine id=2 and id=1 a second time.

Comment: I asked why in the first row of the requested output you combined `id = 1` with `id = 1`, but you do not combine `id = 2` with `id = 2`. Anyhow, in the last line of the code in my answer, it filters existing combinations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a merging index with:

```
df['temp'] = 1
```

And then merge the `dataframe` to itself with:

```
merged_df = df.merge(df, on='temp', suffixes=('A', 'B')).drop('temp', axis=1)
```

If you don't want the combinations of the same `id_number`, do finally:

```
merged_df = merged_df[merged_df['id_numberA'] != merged_df['id_numberB']]
```

And if you don't want duplicated mixes of `id_numberA` and `id_numberB`, do finally instead:

```
merged_df = merged_df[merged_df['id_numberA'] < merged_df['id_numberB']]
```